# Paste a given variable that resembles a path instead of the path itself -- glob

Tags: python, glob

I want to use `path` as my path instead of copying my current folder path's using `glob`.

```py
import  glob  
    
path  = os.getcwd()
glob.glob(path*'.jpg')
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or something similar, if yes, please post the error.

Comment: Did you mean something like `f'{path}/*.jpg'` or `path + '/*.jpg'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
import  glob  
path  = os.getcwd()
glob.glob(f'{path}/*.jpg')
```